# Use of unicode-math results in "unprintable" PDF

Tags: pdf, fontspec, unicode, printing, unicode-math

In the following example, if I uncomment the inclusion of `unicode-math`, I still get an PDF that shows up fine in my PDF Viewer (Evince), but none of the equation shows up in print. Why is that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{Asana Math}
% uncomment the previous two lines to get ``unprintable'' PDF

\begin{document}

magnetic constant $\mu_0 = 4\pi·10^{-7} \frac{\mathrm{H}}{\mathrm{m}}$ 

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** After updating to TL2013, the problem still persists. I guess some printer drivers have problems with the generated PDF (trying it on a Brother HL-5350DN btw). When I convert the PDF to PostScript with pdftops, the resulting *.ps file prints just fine. I'll try with my Canon printer at home later.

**Edit 2:** My Canon printer (MP-600R, with the default Ubuntu drivers) is doing the same thing, no equation.

**Edit 3:** Output of `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
CELWMH+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
TRFNXO+Asana-Math                    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
GZWLZZ+Asana-Math                    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
```

Comment: No problem here; LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, TeX Live 2013

Comment: Hm, I'll try updating. Still on TL2012.

Comment: @Psirus works for me: TL2012 and TL2013, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, with Evince and Okular.

Comment: It shows on all PDF viewers, as far as I can tell, but when I print it (physically), the equation is missing.

Comment: What sort of printer are you printing to? Using what driver? Have you tried ``printing as image''?

Comment: What does `pdffonts` say? (`pdffonts` comes as part of xpdf and/or poppler)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz see my edit.

Comment: Related to this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213201/libertine-ebgaramond-garbled-when-printed-from-evince

Answer (score 1):

This is not guaranteed to work, but it is always worth trying when you have a font problem:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
```

replacing "`in.pdf`" with the PDF you have, and "`out.pdf`" with some convenient filename.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly, it didn't help.