# Libertine, ebgaramond garbled when printed from Evince

Tags: fonts, pdftex, printing, linux, debian

If I try to print a PDF produced with `pdflatex` from within the Evince document viewer on Debian Wheezy, the print output is garbled. This is also true if I "print to file": it looks as shown below.

It displays fine on the screen, however. If I print the original PDF with `lpr` from the terminal, it prints fine. (I am using TeXLive2014 installed from TUG, without any Debian `texlive` packages installed.)

This happens when I use `libertine` or `ebgaramond` packages with T1 encoding, but not with default, `lmodern`, `baskervald`, or `tgpagella`. If I compile the same document with LuaLaTeX, it prints fine.

This may just be a bug in Evince, probably fixed two years ago, given Debian stable's slow packaging process. Or perhaps it's just my printer. If so, I will happily delete the question or file a bug report elsewhere.

Is there something I should be doing differently in LaTeX to fix this? Have others experienced the same problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Output when printed on paper or "printed to file":

[image]

Comment: I'd suspect something to do with the way `evince` is passing stuff to `cups` versus the way `lpr` is passing stuff to `cups`. You can enable debugging output for `cups` to get more information about what is going on. (But don't forget you've set it as it is makes the most of the opportunity to chat.) That doesn't rule out a printer driver bug or whatever - it is possible it might be using different drivers. But it might also be using different filters.

Comment: No (but on Ubuntu 14.04).  When printed to file, it credits [cairo](http://cairographics.org) (v. 1.13.1) as producer and creator....

Comment: @jon Yes, when printed to file, the creator is cairo 1.12.2.

Comment: @AndrewCashner I can confirm the bug (also Debian Wheezy+backports)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks - do you know if it's been reported?

Comment: @AndrewCashner I guess these in `evince` are related [#601389](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=601389), [#630400](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=630400) and this one in `libcairo2` [#701218](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701218)

Comment: This is a "me too" comment. But I get this problem with more than one font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `evince` in Gnome3 under Debian Wheezy, which derives from a bug in `cairo`. It is not caused by LaTeX.

Thanks to @HenriMenke for finding the bug reports. These identify `cairo` as the culprit:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692828

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=697639

Apparently the problem is being solved for future releases of Debian. For those of us still using with Wheezy and Gnome, it works to print from the command line with `lp`.